# Starting an activity with alertDialog from a broadcast receiver running a startup

Tags: android, android-intent

first of all I hope I will respect the netiquette of this forum, since this is the first time I use it.

Here is my problem: I have an Android application with the following structure:

1. ***Main Activity*** (display some user indication and some alert dialog depending on SMS content (see 2))
2. ***SMS broadcast receiver*** that runs at startup (it works fine, runs at startup, read the SMS and parse them in the right way).

I would like to be able, when the receiver get the right SMS, to activate the Activity and to display a AlertDialog.
Everythings works fine if I first show the Activity and then leave it (so if the activity go to suspended state), but if I never open the Activity, I'm able only to display the activity itself but not to activate the AlertDialog.

Here is two little pieces of code:

Receiver (code executed when receiving a specific SMS):

```
//Show/start activity
Intent sec=new Intent(context, SecureMessagesActivity.class);
sec.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
context.startActivity(sec);
// Activate AlertDialog
Intent i = new Intent(context.getString(R.string.intentReceivedSuccessSms)).putExtra("some_msg", "I will be sent!");
context.sendBroadcast(i);
Log.v(TAG, "Sent Intent intentReceivedSuccessSms");
```

Activity (defined as singleTop in android manifest):

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    Log.v(TAG, "Performing onCreate");

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setTheme( android.R.style.Theme_Light);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // Manage subscription to intent
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            getString(R.string.intentReceivedSuccessSms));
    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
                AlertDialog.Builder ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                ad.setTitle(getString(R.string.youFoundIt));
                ad.setMessage(getString(R.string.stopTheMusic));
                ad.setIcon(R.drawable.tick);
                ad.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {                             
                            Log.v(TAG, "Received button pressure to stop ringtone");
                       };
                   }
            );
            ad.show();
        }

    };
    //registering our receiver
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
    // End of manage subscription to intent
    //--------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

I think that my problem is releated to the fact that when the app has not been activated, only the Broadcast receiver is active, so I never run the OnCreate method of the Activity. By this way, I think that it is not fine to first start the activity (see comment "Show/start activity") and immediatly after that sending a broadcast message that is accepted by the OnCreate method (and therefore still not registered, since the OnCreate still didn't started when the receiver sent the Intents). 
But I don't understand how to fix it, I think this is a architectural problem.
Please note that if I start the phone, and send 2 messages, this happens:

1. Phone On
2. First SMS
3. Activity Shows up, no AlertDialog
4. Minimize activity (or leave it full screen, doesn't matter)
5. Activity shows up, with AlertDialog

Any help will be appreciated

I wish you an happy new year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can't work for the reason that you already explained yourself:

> If the activity is not yet running, you can't start it and immediately
>   send a broadcast Intent. At the moment you send the broadcast Intent,
>   your activity hasn't yet started so your listener isn't registered.

You should just add the message information directly to the Intent that you use to start your activity, like this:

```
//Show/start activity
Intent sec=new Intent(context, SecureMessagesActivity.class);
sec.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
sec.putExtra("some_msg", "I will be sent!");
context.startActivity(sec);
Log.v(TAG, "Sent Intent intentReceivedSuccessSms");
```

Then, in `onCreate()` and in `onNewIntent()` you can get the extra and use that to show your dialog. You don't need the `BroadcastReceiver` in your activity.

Comment: Thanks a lot David, in fact tonight I had the same idea that you proposed and I finally managed to get the code working fine.
I hope I did the right thing by proposing your message as the solution if I miss something, let me know, it's the first time I use stackoverflow

Comment: Glad you were able to solve the problem and welcome to StackOverflow! You did everything just fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent sec=new Intent(context, Dialog.class);
            sec.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            context.startActivity(sec);
```

And you need this in a Activity!

```
public class Dialog extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    this.getWindow()
    .setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    builder
        .setTitle("Califica la llamada")
        .setMessage("Esto ayudará a brindarte un mejor servicio de telefonía!")

        .setCancelable(true)
        .setPositiveButton("Buena", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();
                finish();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("Mala", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
        {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
            {
                dialog.cancel();
                finish();
            }
        });


    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();



}
}
```